# Firebase runTransactionBlock error maxretry

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this function that updates the user's exp points:

```
func submitExpPoints(_ points: Int, uid: String) {
    let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)

    dbRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData:FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
        print("currentData", currentData.value!)
        var dataToUpdate = currentData.value as? [String : Any]

        var expPoints = dataToUpdate?["expPoints"] as? Int ?? 0
        expPoints += points
        dataToUpdate?["expPoints"] = expPoints
        currentData.value = dataToUpdate
        return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

    }) {(error,commited,snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print("errorrrrr", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
```

The problem i face is that when i change the child from "users" to "stats", the Simulator can not complete the transaction and it returns the maxretry error.

Now, the strangest thing in the whole story (at least for me) is that the same transaction completes fine when it runs from a real device.

And then when i change back the child from "stats" to "users" everything works like a charm on both my iPhone and the Simulator.

Can anyone help me to figure out what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me and it turns out i was using CGFloat instead of Int. I then used Ints in my code but my database already had fractions, so i needed to reset my database and use Ints everywhere.